# One Button but 2 onClick actions

Tags: java, android

I'm working through a general tutorial for making a fact app and when I click the 'next fact' button it works fine and moves onto the next fact. But I would also like to add a source to each fact but it would mean that I would need to have 2 Onclick actions but on 1 button and I'm really not sure how to do this.

I've looked around and I can only find ones for multiple buttons.

**Facts.java:**

```
package com.example.me.myapplication;


public class Facts {
String Facts [] = {
        "Fact 1",
        "Fact 2",

};

int i = 0;

public String nextFact()
{
    i++;
    return Facts[i];
}

}
```

**source.java:**

```
package com.example.me.myapplication;



public class source {
String source [] = {
        "source 1",
        "source 2",
};

int i = 0;

public String nextsource()
{
    i++;
    return source[i];
}
}
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#F44336"
tools:context="com.example.me.myapplication.MainActivity">

<TextView
android:id="@+id/factTextBox"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
android:layout_centerVertical="true"
android:fontFamily="@font/gothamblack"
android:gravity="center"
android:paddingBottom="10dp"
android:paddingLeft="10dp"
android:paddingRight="10dp"
android:paddingTop="10dp"
android:text="fact"
android:textAllCaps="true"
android:textColor="#fff"
android:textSize="25sp"
app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="60dp"
    android:onClick="genFact"
    android:text="Next Fact" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/sourceTextBox"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/factTextBox"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:text="TextView" />

 </RelativeLayout>
```

**MainActivity.java:**

```
package com.example.me.myapplication;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;

import org.w3c.dom.Text;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

TextView factBox;
Facts factHolder = new Facts();

TextView sourceBox;
source sourceHolder = new source();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    factBox = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.factTextBox);
    sourceBox = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.sourceTextBox);
}

public void genFact(View view)
{
    factBox.setText(factHolder.nextFact());
}

public void gensource(View view)
{
    sourceBox.setText(sourceHolder.nextsource());
}
}
```

Comment: You only need to fire 2 actions by calling them from the onClick() event.

Comment: Could you not just have both methods called in a single `onClick` event?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of declaring your on click function in the layout (the .xml file) use the function setOnClickListener and write your own function.

`factBox.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                genFact(factBox); // or whatever you want
        });`

Comment: I've tried using this but it only works when I click the fact on the app. So I tried changing it so it uses the button but now the app wont open. The code used was:
mybutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                genFact(factBox); // or whatever you want
        }});

Comment: you don't need to pass a view in genFact.

Comment: I've tried using this code for it but it doesn't seem to work. The app wont open anymore 
nextbutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                genFact(factBox); // or whatever you want
                gensource(sourceBox);
            }});

Comment: Again you don't have to pass a view in your function you have to write your custom fuction different. Also post the stacktrace

Answer (score 0):

You can use `longClickListner` to view the source link and `onClickListner` to go on next source.

You just need to `return true in the longClickListner` to make both of them work simultaneously.

Answer (score 0):

you can simply use onClick inside a XML, and call onClickListener inside you code.

```
factBox.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            genFact(factBox); // or whatever you want
    });
```

And a second one to be called from XML

```
public void genFact(View view) {

factBox.setText(factHolder.nextFact()); }
```